# SQL list of results in one table based on two columns equalling specific values in another table

Tags: sql-server

So I am looking to find a list of 'accounts' from TableA (accounts table) that have two particular values set in Table B (Information table).

Table A has a list of all of the accounts, opening date, reference etc and Table B contains these account numbers with all the specific account information.

I am wanting to a list of accounts that have has two particular values set in table B.

Tables and columns:

Table A: Account Number,  Is account still open?

Table B: Account number, Information Number, Information data

I want a list of all accounts in TableA where in Table B information number 1 is equal to 10 and information number 2 is equal to 20.

Sample data:

Table A

```
Account Number  Is Account still open
1234            Yes
12345           No
123456          Yes
```

Table B

```
Account  Number  Information Number Information data
1234     1       10
1234     2       20
12345    1       10
12345    2       20
123456   1       1000
123456   2       2000
```

So once my SQL query has been executed it should give a final result of account 1234 as it is the only account where information number 1 = 10, information number 2 = 20 and the account is still open.

So far the only thoughts I have had is using a CASE or Union syntax. I am still learning the SQL language so any help would be appreciated greatly. Hopefully I have explained okay.

Comment: Reformat your question, pls.

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: is information number 1 and 2 different column?

Answer (score 0):

Use INNER JOIN

`SELECT ta.ACCOUNT_NUMBER FROM TABLE A as ta
INNER JOIN TABLE B as tb
ON ta.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = tb.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
WHERE ta.IS_ACCOUNT_OPEN = 'yes'
AND tb.INFORMATION_DATA IN ( 10, 20 )`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA A
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tableB
             WHERE information number 1 = 10
               AND information number 2 = 20
               AND AccountNumber = A.AccountNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `case when` and `join`

```
select a.* from TableA a inner join     
 (select 
    case when (number=1 and information_number=10)
     or  (number=2 and information_number=20) then account_number else 
  null as account_number 
    from tableB 
) b on a.account_number =b.account_number
```